# Can't log into website having migrated to sql server from mysql

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, asp-classic

I can seem to get a correct connection to my website have moved from a mysql database to a sql server 2008 r2 db. The website is written in classic asp and uses conn.inc file. The contents of this file is as below. I have **** the password.

```
<%
Dim strConn
Dim conn
strConn = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=chintranet2;Database=Gremlin;Uid=Gremlin;Pwd=********;"
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.ConnectionString= strConn
conn.Open
%>
```

The error I get is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 error '80040e4d' 

Login failed for user 'Gremlin'. 

/Gremlinv4/connections/conn.inc, line 7
```

Can anyoine please shed any light on this. The user is created in sql server and has permissions assigned as "owner".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Usually connection strings to ms sql look like `"data source=chintranet2;Initial Catalog=Gremlin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Gremlin;Password=PlainPassHere;"` Also user should be mapped to Gremlin database login.

Comment: I'm doing pretty much the same thing and here's what my Connection string looks like: `PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=chintranet2;Initial Catalog=Gremlin;User Id=Gremlin;Password=*********;`

Comment: Have you tested connecting from the command line: `sqlcmd -S chintranet2 -U Gremlin -P ******* -d Gremlin` If that gives the same error then you should check that the Gremlin login has the correct password and is not disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Best Guess so far, you did not enabled your user in the db.. use the following script as a referance and see if you get a better result:

```
Use [myDBName]
CREATE LOGIN [Gremlin] 
WITH PASSWORD=N'123', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[myDBName], 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

ALTER LOGIN [Gremlin] ENABLE --Here is my best guess.

USE [myDBName]
CREATE USER [Gremlin] FOR LOGIN [Gremlin];
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'Gremlin'
```